# Almacenar datos en TABLEVIEW en SWIFT

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Trato de hacer una especie de programa para registrar mesas en Xcode. Tengo una Class con 2 variables, nombre y comensales, un array para almacenar los objetos y su función para almacenar. Tengo un NavController donde la primera vista (el root) es una TableView, en el siguiente ViewController de la NavController (conectado como Show), tengo 2 textFields para capturar los datos de mi Class, con su button para agregar objetos al array a través de un "prepare". Al volver atrás en el botón Back de la Navigation para ver la TableView, sigue vacía. No soy capaz de cargar los datos de un ViewController y que se muestren en otro en la TableView. No se si me falta algo para que todo funcione, soy nuevo en Swift.

```
// Mi Clase simple
public class Mesas {
var nombre: String = ""
var numComensales: Int = 0

var listaMesas: [Mesas] = []

func almacenarMesas(nuevaMesa: Mesas) {
    listaMesas.append(nuevaMesa)
}
```

}

```
// Primer ViewController de la NavController donde está la TableView
import UIKit

class VCTableViewMesas: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var nuevaMesa = Mesas()


@IBOutlet weak var tableViewMesas: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableViewMesas.dataSource = self
    tableViewMesas.delegate = self
    
}

}   // Fin VCTableViewMesas







// Extension DataSource
extension VCTableViewMesas {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nuevaMesa.listaMesas.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->      UITableViewCell {
    let miCelda = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "miCelda", for: indexPath)   as! TVCellMesas
    
    miCelda.textLabel?.text = nuevaMesa.listaMesas[indexPath.row].nombre
    
    return miCelda
}
}   // Fin Extension DataSource



// Extension Delegate
extension VCTableViewMesas {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}


// Funcion BORRAR
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        self.nuevaMesa.listaMesas.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableViewMesas.reloadData()
    }
}

}   // Fin extension Delegate


//Segundo ViewController para capturar datos
import UIKit


class VCNuevaMesa: UIViewController {

var nombreTemporal = ""
var comensalesTemporal = 0



@IBOutlet weak var textFieldNombre: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldComensales: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    
}


@IBAction func agregar(_ sender: Any) {
    if let textoNombre = textFieldNombre.text {
        nombreTemporal = textoNombre
    }
    
    if let textoComensales = textFieldComensales.text {
        comensalesTemporal = Int(textoComensales)!
    }
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let envioDatos = segue.destination as! VCTableViewMesas
    
    envioDatos.nuevaMesa.nombre = nombreTemporal
    envioDatos.nuevaMesa.numComensales = comensalesTemporal

    envioDatos.nuevaMesa.almacenarMesas(nuevaMesa: envioDatos.nuevaMesa)
}

}   // Fin VCNuevaMesa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay 2 cosas que cambiaría. La primera tu clase Mesas. La clase debería guardar sólo lo relevante a 1 mesa, su nombre y el numComensales, de forma que cuando recojas los datos tengas tu mesa, única, solo tiene lo relacionado con la mesa. Lo demás no es importante para la clase

```
let mesa = Mesa(numero: 1, comensales: 4)
```

El array de mesas lo guardaria en el tableViewController como una variable del controlador:

```
var mesas: [Mesa] = []
```

Ahora viene lo segundo, el porqué no se te guarda la mesa que has puesto en el segundo viewController. No le pasas de ninguna forma esa tabla actualizada y deberia solo pasar la mesa que has creado, no el array completo, por eso lo de sacar el array del modelo. Tienes un navigationController, por lo que el back te lo va a hacer solo. Lo único que tienes que hacer es pasar la Mesa creada en el viewController al tableViewController. Lo suyo sería hacer un delegado entre la tabla y el viewController.
Creas un protocolo, lo puedes hacer en el viewController, antes de la declaración de la clase

```
protocol MesasDelegate{
   func nueva(mesa: Mesa)
}
```

Dentro del viewController, te creas un delegado

```
var delegate: MesasDelegate?
```

En el tableViewController, cuando se ejecuta el prepareforSegue, has de asignarle quien es el delegado. Una vez creado el controlador destino, le asignas el delegado, que es el tableViewController. Tendrás un método similar a este:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? VCNuevaMesa{
        destination.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Ahora solo te falta pasarle la mesa creada a la tabla cuando hayas rellenado los datos. En tu funcion agregar de viewController, creas la mesa y la pasas.

```
@IBAction func agregar(_ sender: Any) {
if let textoNombre = textFieldNombre.text,
   let textoComensales = Int(textFieldComensales.text) {
    let mesa = Mesa(numero: textoNombre, comensales: textoComensales
    //aqui le paso la mesa a la tabla
    self.delegate?.nueva(mesa: mesa)
  }
}
```

Ahora solo nos falta rellenar el protocolo. Haces una extension de UITableViewController solo para ese protocolo.

```
extension VCTableMesas: MesasDelegate {
 func nueva(mesa: Mesa) {
   self.mesas.append(mesa)
   self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
}
```

Comment: Genial. Me sirvió hacerlo a través del Protocolo. Funciona a la perfección y justo lo que quería. Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una clase estática para que almacenes los valores en la variable `listaMesas`. Tendrías tu clase así:

```
public class Mesas {
    static let mesa = Mesas(nombre: "", numComensales: 0)
    var nombre: String = ""
    var numComensales: Int = 0
    
    var listaMesas: [Mesas] = []
    
    init(nombre: String, numComensales: Int) {
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.numComensales = numComensales
    }
    
    func almacenarMesas(nuevaMesa: Mesas) {
        listaMesas.append(nuevaMesa)
    }
}
```

En tu `tableViewController` puedes acceder a la variable `listaMesas` así:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Mesas.mesa.listaMesas.count
}
```

Bien, ahora en el `viewController` en donde ingresas esa información lo harías así:

```
let newMesa = Mesas(nombre: textNombre.text, numComensales: Int(textComensales.text)!)
Mesas.mesa.almacenarMesas(nuevaMesa: newMesa)
```

Al hacer back a tu `tableViewController` puedes ver que se muestra el nuevo dato sin necesidad de hacer nada adicional. Puedes verificar haciendo unos print.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->      UITableViewCell {
    let miCelda = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "miCelda", for: indexPath)   as! TVCellMesas
    
    miCelda.textLabel?.text = Mesas.mesa.listaMesas[indexPath.row].nombre
    
    return miCelda
}
```